# Changed URL to pages, but still redirects to Pages?

Tags: 2010, powershell, url, splist, internet-sites

I have an external website which needs to show URL in lowercase only. I don’t want to use URL Rewrite or any third party tool. Instead we decided to change the actual URL’s of the Pages Library. I’ve done that by using the following script.

```
if ($list.RootFolder.Url.Equals("Pages"))
{
    $ListURL = $SPWeb.url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url
    Write-Host $ListURL
    Write-Host "Title: " $list.Title ", Url: " $list.RootFolder.Url -foregroundcolor magenta

    #try 
    #{
        $list.Title = $list.Title.ToLower()
        $list.RootFolder.MoveTo($list.RootFolder.Url.ToLower())
    #}
    #catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] 
    #{
    #    write-host 'RuntimeException'
    #}

    $list.Update()

    Write-Host "Title: " $list.Title ", Url: " $list.RootFolder.Url -foregroundcolor darkgreen
}

if ($SPWeb -ne $null)
{
    $SPWeb.Dispose()
}
```

... which outputs ...

```
http://dev. ... /contact/Pages
Title:  Pages , Url:  Pages
RuntimeException
Title:  pages , Url:  pages
```

Yes, I get a Runtime Error, but the URL and list name actually changes (se image).

[image]

If I go to a page in the pages library directly, I get the new URL, but if I write the short hand URL (without `/pages/default.aspx`) I get the previous initial uppercase letter `/Pages` URL. My question is why, and how do I resolve this?

Comment: First of all, the MoveTo method doesn't return anything, so you can't use it to assign a new value to the `$list.RootFolder.Url` property. Let's see if it works better if you leave that part out and just simply: `$list.RootFolder.MoveTo($list.RootFolder.Url.ToLower())`

Comment: @Norbert That's why there was a RuntimeException which was solved by your method. Thanks! But browsing to the web without the 'pages' specified redirects to 'Pages' with a capital P which I wanted to avoid. Can't imagine why that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirected to the *Pages* library instead of *pages* because there is a property on the web level, which holds the old URL of the default page. In order to fix this, you will need to insert the following snippet into your script:

```
$folder = $SPWeb.RootFolder;
$folder.WelcomePage = $folder.WelcomePage.Replace("Pages","pages");
$folder.Update();
```

I hope this helped. If not, please feel free to ask me for details.

Comment: +1 Super! It worked as expected! I've taken the liberty to generalize your code on row 2 to `$folder.WelcomePage = $folder.WelcomePage.ToLower()` Thanks for your input!